# Click the forgot password link it will show like that error message email field required

Tags: codeigniter

I want to display error message if i click the forgot password link it will show like that error message Email field required.[this is the forgot password page images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKTZ1.png)

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Index.php/Login_cntrl/login" method="POST" >

                        <div class="field-wrap">
                            <label class="view-label">Email Address</label>
                            <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" id="email" class="input-control" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="field-wrap">
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>" />
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('password'); ?></span>

                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link btn-nobg" id="btn-show-forgot" >Forgot ?</a>  

                        </div>


                        <div class="field-wrap">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit" name="ulogin" id="ulogin" >Login</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field-wrap">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link btn-nobg" id="btn-show-signup">NEW User? Sign up</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: can you post your controller?

Answer (score 0):

if you use jQuery just like this

```
$('#btn-show-forgot').click(function(event) {
/* Check Email Value */
var email = $('#email').val();
if (email == ''){
alert('email must not empty')}
});
```

or try like this

```
$(document).on('click','#btn-show-forgot',function(event){
var email = $('#email').val();
if (email == ''){
alert('email must not empty')}
});
```

Comment: sorry i have tried with that code but it's not working

Comment: I was edited you can try the code, and send me what error on the console so i can help you

Comment: after click on ok button in alert pop up empty fields are going to next page without validation

Comment: the problem is on #btn-show-forgot or on ulogin, and what your means a OK button?

Comment: after click the forgot button with  empty email field,one pop wil shown email field is required,click ok on pop up it will redirect to next page without email field validation

Comment: i will attached images above please go through it(two different form images)

Answer (score 0):

try this and according as you needs

```
$('#btn-show-forgot').click(function(event) {
var email = $('#email').val();
if (email == ''){
var r = confirm("Press a button!");
if (r == true) {
window.location = //your landing page
} else {
txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
}
}
});`
```

Comment: sorry i have tried with that code but it's not working